# Error windows with specified version of firefox and selenium

Tags: windows, python-2.7, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am using python and selenium. 
On my pc, i have two version of firefox

the first one in ProgrammFiles is version 21
The latest one is in `"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox"`

I would like to run selenium on the lastest one, but i got an error message:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
binary = FirefoxBinary("C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox")
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.48.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 77, in **init**
>       self.binary, timeout),
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.48.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py", line 49, in **init**
>       self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.48.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 67, in launch_browser
>       self._start_from_profile_path(self.profile.path)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.48.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 90, in _start_from_profile_path
>       env=self._firefox_env)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in **init**
>       errread, errwrite)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
>       startupinfo)
>
> WindowsError: [Error 5] アクセスが拒否されました。

Do you have any hint to give me to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firefox binary path that needs to be passed in `FirefoxBinary('')` should be the path for the executable 'firefox.exe'.

E.g.:

```
ff_binary = FirefoxBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=ff_binary)
```

PS: In your case, the path you've specified is the path where the firefox profile is stored normally.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx for your answer. But the path is correct. I have 2 versions of firefox, and the one i would like to access is in the path i mentionned.

Comment: Ok. In that case, did you try appending 'firefox.exe' to the path (like shown in my answer above)?

Comment: I can't believe that is just that. It is working with the .exe... but I am sure I already tried it. well, thanks ^^

Comment: Glad, I could help! :)